# how to get the selected contacts into an array from my emulator in android

Tags: android

hai all.....
            I am  displying all my emulator  contacts into my appliaction.I want to select some of the contacts and putting into an array...can anyone show me the code ...please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
try like this,
In onCreate,

```
Button existing_contacts = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_contact_existing);

existing_contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent intent_contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    /*contacts.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    contacts.setData(People.CONTENT_URI);*/
                    startActivityForResult(intent_contacts, 0);
                    //displayContacts();


                }
             });
```

and 
after onCreate,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String name,mailid,id;
    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case 0:
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK )
            {
                Uri contactdata  = data.getData();

                Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactdata, null, null, null, null);


                if(cur.moveToFirst())
                {
                    id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String[]{id}, null); 
                    emailCur.moveToFirst();
                    String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));


                    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    //mailid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    mailid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID));
                    //Toast.makeText(context_contact, "Name:"+name+"\nmailid:"+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//your code to put data in arraylist                        
/*Intent intent_add_invitees = new Intent(<ClassContext>,<ActivityName>.class);
                    intent_add_invitees.putExtra("invitee_name", name);
                    intent_add_invitees.putExtra("invitee_mailid", email);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent_add_invitees);
                    finish();*/

                }
            }

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: hai Jaydeep Khamar,Thanks for your help..I am displaying all phonebook contacts with checkbox in each row into my application.suppose i am displying 6 contacts in emulator.Now I want to select 3 contacts and put those selected contacts into arraylist or something else.....

Comment: You will get only those contacts which you select from phonebook screen

Comment: hai ....I am trying to execute the above code But it shows error ..... Send_invitations cannot be resolved to a type or Contact cannot be resolved to a type....what should i write in Send_invitations.class...

Comment: These are the names of the activities used in my project.Use ur Activity names.

Comment: I am new to android..please help me out.....what should i write in the next activity..I hope that my search ends here...

Comment: Actually i tried like this but it gives improper results...that means whenever i click on a particular item it shows other item in the logcat